# Why did Sally Roe use her real name on the envelope for her letters to Tom Harris?

Tags: character-analysis, frank-peretti, piercing-the-darkness

After her supposed death in the beginning of *Piercing the Darkness*, Sally Roe started writing to Tom Harris after learning about the bogus lawsuit against him. However, she puts her real name on the envelope, which caused her letters to be intercepted by her pursuers. Why did she do that? It seems like a rather clumsy mistake by someone who would rather not be found.